# Excel: Hiding a group of objects based on the contents of the shape

Tags: excel, vba

Within Excel, I have created a group of shapes, these comprise of some check boxes and a white rectangle. I've named these "grouponeone". I have also created a rectangle called "oneonebutton"

What I would like to happen is that when the rectangle "oneonebutton" is inactive the text frame references a a named cell (call it "namedcell"). When clicked it changes to "Select Options" and the group is shown underneath the button. The check boxes, when clicked plot scatter values on a graph. When clicked again it reverts back to initial state.

This is my code so far, but I'm stuck and being new to VBA I've been hacking about with out much luck. Help very much appreciated.

```
Sub checkboxmacro()

If SelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Range("namedcell") Then
    group11.Visible= False
    SelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Select Options"
Else
    group11.Visible = True
    SelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Range("experimentoneonename")
End If

End Sub
```

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far looks OK to me (some suggested changes below).

```
Sub Tester()
    Const STR_SELECT As String = "Select Options (click here when done)"
    Dim shp As Shape, tr As TextRange2, grp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    Set tr = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
    Set grp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("grpOne")

    If tr.Characters.Text <> STR_SELECT Then
        tr.Characters.Text = STR_SELECT
        grp.Visible = True
    Else
        tr.Characters.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("namedcell")
        grp.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

How to proceed might depend in part on what type of checkboxes you have.

Eg: if you use Forms checkboxes then you can link them all up tp something like the sub below (switching the action you take based on the name of the checkbox)

```
Sub Checker()
    Dim ac As String

    ac = Application.Caller
    Debug.Print ac, ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(ac).Value
    'do something based on checkbox name and value...

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Thanks. I did add a group box to hold all of the check boxes inside, instead of a rectangle but it works perfect!